# How to animate an element that is loaded via ajax when scrolling?

Tags: jquery, ajax, animation

I'm trying to fade in -or animate in any way- the appearance of an element that is loaded with ajax when the user scroll to a certain point.

I've checked a lot of tutorials and other related questions but all I've found are scripts fired with a click. I tried the following code and other versions (see below) and managed to create the animation, but the loaded element keeps flashing:

```
<script>
        var height = $('.placeholder').offset().top;

        $(window).on('scroll', function() {
            var heightScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            var heightWin = $(window).height();
            var heightTotal = heightScroll + heightWin;
            var stop = 0;
            if ((heightTotal > height) && (stop === 0)) {
                $('.placeholder div').load('ajax/ajax-meditacion.html');
                $('.placeholder div .wrap').hide().fadeIn('slow');
                stop++;
            }
        }); 
</script>
```

Other things I've tried with no luck:

- `$('.placeholder div').hide('fast').load('ajax/ajax-meditacion.html').fadeIn('slow');` instead of having it in two statements.
- End the fuction with `return false;` without `var stop`.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Looks like you'd need to raise the scope of `var stop` a level to outside of the event listener, it now resets on each scroll event. Since it is then always `0`, it will keep on loading the external page.

Comment: @Shikkediel Yay! You're right! now it works, thanks a lot! :)